# Electronic selector / gate

Tags: switches

The circuit that I am looking for is supposed to work as follows:

The circuit has, besides power, three inputs, and two outputs.

The circuit is supposed to act like a get, and let an analog signal pass through it.

The first input is the analog signal input, the first output is the same signal output.

The second input is a close trigger. Presence of a signal in this trigger will cause the circuit to close, if it were open, and stop the analog signal to pass through it.

The second output is a signal given off by the circuit when the analog signal passing through it is cut off due to the close trigger - a close confirmation.

Finally the third input is a open trigger. regardless of the presence of the close trigger signal, the open trigger should open the circuit, and let the analog signal pass through.

If I connected the close confirm signal of this circuit to the open trigger of an identical circuit, which in turn would trigger a third identical circuit to open by its close confirm being connected to the open trigger of the third, and then connected their close triggers together, then the first signal at the close trigger will first cause the first circuit (initially open) to close, cutting off the analog signal passing through it, and the close confirm signal will trigger the second one (initially closed) to open (the close confirm drives the open trigger of the second, and the open trigger, regardless of presence of the close trigger, will open the circuit), letting the second circuit to let another analog signal pass through. Next close trigger will close the second circuit, and open the the third.

How can I start constructing such a circuit? Is there an IC solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Inputs: I1, I2 and I3
Outputs: O1 and O2

The following table shows what I have understood from your question. Assumed that I2, I3 and O2 can be considered as digital signal

$$\begin{array}{cccc} &\style{color:blue}{\mathbf{I_2}} &\style{color:blue}{\mathbf{I_3}} &\style{color:blue}{\mathbf{O_1}} &\style{color:blue}{\mathbf{O_2}}\\
&0 &0 &I_1 &0\\
&1 &0 &0 &1\\
&0 &1 &I_1 &0\\
&1 &1 &I_1 &0\end{array}$$

Now implementing this logic is simple if you have a \$\mathrm{4\times 1}\$ analog multiplexer (eg:[74HC4052](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4052.pdf)).

Connect I2 and I3 to the select lines of the MUX. And feed all inputs of MUX except the second input with I1. Connect ground to the second input and O1 to the output.

You can implement \$O_2=I_2\overline{I_3}\$ with MUX or gates.

Comment: yes, that is the correct table. Looking up the multiplexer. thank you.

Comment: Now if I make a cycle of the three identical circuits, connecting O2 of the third one to the I3 of the first, then the only issue I will face is voltage regulation...